# How to parse JSON array in JSP and form a String

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have a `JSON` array of strings which is nothing but the response received from a server. Now I would like iterate through the array object and form a single string and, perform string manipulation on the whole string. For example, I have the following `JSON` object

```
      "data": {
          "details": [
            "Toyota",
            "Mazda",
            "Hyundai"
          ]
        }
```

I knew that I can simply print it as an HTML element using `ForEach` as below,

```
<c:forEach items="${details}" var="item" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${!status.last}
      <span>${item}, </span>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${status.last}">
      <span>and ${item}</span>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

But here I do not want to in this manner but like to form a complete string like `Toyota Mazda Hyundai` and then JSP Standard Tag Library as indicated [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_join.htm), then pass that string as an argument to `i18n` key like as below,

snippet from `i18n` common properties,

```
car.makers=Car makers {0}
```

snippet from my `jsp`

```
<c:set var="carmakers"><fmt:message key="car.makers"><fmt:param>${thefullstring}</fmt:param></fmt:message></c:set>
```

The full string is the one which I'm trying to generate out of `JSON` array.
How to form a String from `JSON` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on how to format a String from the JSON array. The implementation is as below,

```
  <c:set var="models" value=""/>
  <c:forEach items="${carmodels}" var="item" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${!status.last}">
        <c:set var="models" value="${models}${item},${' '}"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${status.last}">
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty models}">
          <c:set var="models" value="${models}and${' '}${item}"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <c:set var="models" value="${item}"/>
        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
    </c:if>
  </c:forEach>
```